# Why is ASP.NET FormsAuthentication cookie not authenticating user?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, membership, formsauthentication

I have a site that uses the default SqlMembershipProvider and FormsAuthentication. I can use the built-in Login Controls and/or programmatically call all the methods to authenticate a user and get the same result - the user is authenticated and a cookie is created, but the cookie does not appear to be valid since I can't get into any page that requires authentication.

There is no real code to show for the default Login Control since it should just "work", but here is the custom code I tried:

```
protected void ctrlLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
   if (Membership.ValidateUser(ctrlLogin.UserName, ctrlLogin.Password))
   {
      FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(ctrlLogin.UserName, ctrlLogin.RememberMeSet);
      /*
       * I also tried this:
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(ctrlLogin.UserName, ctrlLogin.RememberMeSet);
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
         Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
      Response.Redirect("/index.aspx");
       */
   }
   else
   {
      ctrlLogin.FailureText = "Invalid Username/Password Combination";
   }
}
```

With this code, **Membership.ValidateUser() succeeds**, and both **FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage() and FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage() successfully set a cookie** - that cookie just doesn't work to verify my authentication. I have confirmed this by deleting all my cookies and watching them get created again with FireCookie. The cookie name matches what I have in my web.config, the domain is "/", and the expiration date is as expected (see below).

Here are the relevant sections of my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login/index.aspx" name=".SoeAuth" protection="All"
    slidingExpiration="true" timeout="525599" domain=""></forms>
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="[MY_CS]" applicationName="[MY_APPNAME]"
      minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
      enablePasswordReset="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" requiresUniqueEmail="true"
      name="SqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

It should be noted that I also added a machineKey entry in my web.config file based on a suggestion from [a very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953212/why-isnt-aspaux-cookie-being-validated-by-formsauthentication) (which didn't solve my problem). Also, for reference, the timeout=525599 above is 1 minute less than a year for my persistent cookies.

Comment: I know ValidateUser doesn't actually set a cookie. My point in mentioning that is that is is required when programmatically authenticating a user, and it proves that I'm not just typing the wrong username or password. The code above shows the full process.

Comment: What is `IsAuthenticated` set to when you revisit after logging in? I don't think RedirectFromLoginPage sets the auth cookie either, except in specific circumstances.

Comment: User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false.

Comment: Try setting path to / in your forms config and it might work as is. The cookie is only set when `CookiesSupported || IsPathWithinAppRoot(current, returnUrl))`, otherwise just call SetAuthCookie explicitly before redirecting.

Comment: is your cookie sent over in the next request (use fiddler and check the request header) and for giggle, lower your timeout to say 600 for testing. Also remove the domain="" - you arent setting it so remove it.

Comment: I tried removing the domain="" and also setting it to "/". No change. My browser supports cookies, and the path is within the current application. I also tried the SetAuthCookie() method as seen in my sample code above.

Comment: @Adam Yes, the cookie is sent in all requests after it is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem:

Since I was able to create a simple working test project with the exact same source code, I determined that the problem was in the web.config file.

Going through each section, I discovered in the `'system.web / httpModules'` section I had a `<clear/>` element. This removed the `<add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule"/>` module defined in machine-level web.config file. Adding it back in instantly fixed the problem.

*It sure would have been nice to get an error message when I tried to use the FormsAuthentication methods and that module wasn't even loaded...*

Comment: how did you added it ? as I face the same problem

Comment: Either remove the <clear/> or add the <add .../> element below it.

Comment: Spent ages trying to figure out why it wasn't authenticating. In newer versions it may be a <remove> element <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />. Upvoting answer