# Form Authentication from webmethod

Tags: asp.net, webforms, webmethod, form-authentication

I am trying to set a cookie from withing a WebMethod like this

```
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.UserName,
                DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), user.RememberMe, user.Groups);

            //Encrypt the ticket.
            String encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

            //Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
            HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

            if (true == user.RememberMe)
                authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;

            //Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

Now I want to redirect the user, after the user logged in, to a different page. I know I can't do this from the WebMethod. I return true to the jQuery Ajax call and then redirect the user using this

```
window.location.href = "/Pages/NonIssued";
```

But the redirection fails and takes keeps me in the login page, How can I Make the user logged in.

This is what I have in my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Pages/LoginPage.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="/Pages/NonIssued.aspx" path="/">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <!--<allow roles="SDI\asfsadf aered 765" />
  <deny roles="SDI\SRD-Epac SQL Admins" />-->
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: try with slidingexpiration =false and one more thing you can  do  is check if cookie is getting saved or not using dev tools (press F12)

Comment: The cookie is not being saved :(. What should I do?

Comment: on your second page, are you decrypting the cookie??

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_formsauthenticationtickets

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450245/why-is-asp-net-formsauthentication-cookie-not-authenticating-user

this may help you!

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper I found the cookie by using firefox dev tools. The value is empty!. Don't know what to do!

Comment: Even me too. looking at your code it seems perfect! have you visited the link I provided?

Comment: can you try without encrypt/decrypt?

Comment: I tried to set it directly like this FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false); and it worked  I am not sure why the other one is not working!

Comment: Strange, isn't it ? well , you can post the answer. may be it can be helpful to someone.

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper I don't consider what I did to be the correct answer as it didn't explain why the code in the question isn't working.